# what is the event for Vue.Draggable un-choose?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, rubaxa-sortable, vue.draggable

I know there is event for choose but not sure what should I use for un-choose/un-select, for my use case I cannot use `@end` event.

```
<draggable :list="list" @choose ="onChoose">
```

Here is the doc which I am referring.
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events

Comment: FWIW, it looks like scrollablejs fires a 'unchoose' event when an item is dropped, but it doesn't seem to be documented (so use at your own risk).  you'd have to pass in 'onUnchoose' to the options prop on the draggable component, since vue.draggable doesn't handle it like the other events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be

```
<draggable :list="list" @choose ="onChoose" @unchoose="onUnchoose">
```

From the Vue.Draggable docs

> Support for Sortable events:
>
> start, add, remove, update, end, choose, **unchoose**, sort, filter, clone

Comment: `unchoose` event was not available a year back  i.e. `Jul 11 '18` when I asked this question. I am not sure, maybe it's added now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specfic item undraggable, use the [move](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#move) prop.
Returning false will prevent the item from being draggable:

```
function onMoveCallback(evt, originalEvent){
   ...
    // return false; — for cancel
}
```